# upload nodejs application to AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I want to deploy my app (Nodejs + Mongodb) in EC2. After installed Nodejs and MongoDb in EC2 instances, I do not know how to upload my source code to instances and where to upload it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you created your instances you should have also created an ssh key that you use to access the EC2 instance via SSH which you clearly have if you were able to install additional packages.

You can use this same key and method to connect to the instance with [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) and upload the files you want like that.

You could also use [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) to copy the files directly from the commandline or from a custom script.

With regard to *where* to upload the files - that all depends on you. What web servers are you using (if at all). Depending on your application you need to select a location that is accessible via your web server. The default location for an apache server would be `/var/www`

Comment: Another approach that I like is to use a Git repo to manage your application. From there, you can simply git clone your repo onto the EC2 instance.

Comment: @NickMitchinson - provided that it is an open source project - but this is not always the case and uploading your source code to a public site is not always an option.

Comment: But yes - that's how we do it at my current job. This usually requires a paid service though...

Comment: I believe that bitbucket provides free private repo's; I may be wrong though. Even so, a basic github account will run you 7$/month and give you 5 private repos.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WinScp (https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) to have an "explorer like" access to your EC2 linux:[image]

Note: The ppk private key was created using the "node.pem" key from AWS. But you must make it accessible by running:

```
chown :Users node.pem
chmod 400 node.pem
```